# float clear footer margin white gap issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem with a white gap at the bottom of my html doc and believe that the problem lies in a combination improper use of float, clear, display properties but I am not sure.

I have a footer contained within the page's main holder div. This footer has a margin-top of 50px to give desired layout but the problem is that on a smaller screen (like my my laptop, which is a standard sized laptop) there appears to be a white gap between the html and bottom of the page - it appears like not only the holder div but that the html does not "clear" past the footer with the margin-top.

Here is the url since it's tricky to explain, I believe that I'm close to solving having fiddled around with float, clear and removing the margin but cannot quite get there... any ideas? I'd be grateful for pointers:

tinyurl.com/7ywoqpf

Here is a picture of the issue.
[image: css issue]

Comment: I sware that in the right bottom I can see a part of the background picture but after 30 px from the right there's blank part. Do you have another `div` in that position with `background-color:white` or `z-index`?

Comment: Hey you have already put this question i have seen today itself, any ways i am not getting issue can you please give screen shot in which you point out what is the issue, that will great help. m waiting

Comment: @happy sing sure but where or how to I add a screen to this forum? whats usual practice here? thanks

Comment: you can take screen shot from your PC and edit you question above text area there is a small image icon once you click on it, you will get file upload dialog and from there you can upload you screen shot and update your answer.

Comment: @happy sing: thank you I will certainly use that in future. For now it seems that someone has posted a screen below

Comment: @Doug you can see my answer have screen shot in which footer space is removed. If this you want then i will be very happy to solve your issue.

Comment: Hey check my updated answer try it and reply me

Answer (score 1):

Try below css - edit your style.css line 115

```
footer {
    border-top: 2px solid gray;
    width: 805px;
}
```

Remove  `margin-top: 50px;`

See below image to see the changes in footer white space removed.

[image]

**Update:**

Try to remove this one also style.css line 212

```
html {height:100% }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but how should I achieve the 50px gap between the footer and the image gallery? Also, to be clear, the background image should be at the very bottom with no space.

Comment: yes actually this is how the CS was before, I added the html {height:100%} because though the html doc looked fine on my laptop it did not on larger screens. i.e. the problem is reversed, I can have the solution for small or large screen but not for both! If you check your solution by zooming out using the browser zoom you'll see what I mean. Thanks for your help so far though I'm really grateful

Comment: If you dont mind please have a look on this site http://www.csszengarden.com/ i think this site have your solution because you have given both images from background on body that is giving issues on different resolutions, acc to me you have to use two divs and put the images on that divs and make the position of both the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin-top, you will get rid of the bottom spacing. But you need to move the footer into the body section so that it spans across, not just the inner div.

Comment: I did try taking the footer out of the holder div and removing the margin at the top. This solves one issue but creates another - I need a gap of 50px between the footer and the image gallery